# Connection timed out when connecting the socket

Tags: android, .net, sockets

I am writing code to connect a socket to a server. However, when I try to connect the socket, it throws an exception:

> net.connectexception: connect failed: ETIMEOUT

The exception seems to be thrown at a fixed time like 1min. I have referred to many material and I have done the following:

1. added `permission.internet` to `manifest.xml`.
2. make the Phone and PC under the same WiFi.

But the exception is still thrown.

Here is my code:

```java
btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mThreadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {                           
                        outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                        outputStream.write(floatToByte(a));
                        outputStream.flush();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                         Log.d("send",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                    }
                    catch(NullPointerException e)
                    {
                        Log.d("send",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    });
    btnConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
    btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mThreadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {

                        socket=new Socket("192.168.43.194",9998)
                        System.out.println(socket.isConnected());
                        boolean m=socket.isConnected();
                        if(m) {
                            Log.d("Connect","True");
                        }
                        if(!m){
                            Log.d("Connect","Connect false");
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("Connect",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                    }
                    catch(NullPointerException e){
                        Log.d("Connect",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                    }
                    catch(NetworkOnMainThreadException e){
                        Log.d("Connect",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                    }

                }
            });
```

Here is my logcat:

```
2021-07-07 22:58:56.950 24255-24560/com.example.magickeyboard D/Connect: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.43.194 (port 9998) from /:: (port 57742): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:143)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:570)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:450)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
    at com.example.magickeyboard.Activities.Typing$3$1.run(Typing.java:162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    at libcore.io.Linux.connect(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:95)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:136)
    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:95)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:157)
```

This is the code of my server and I have binded a socket listening on the port.

```java
public class ser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {           
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9998);            
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();           
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024 * 4];
            int temp = 0;            
            while ((temp = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, temp));
            }
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ip address of the PC:

[image]

Comment: Well, lets start with the obvious: are you sure 192.168.43.194 is the correct IP assigned to the PC, and does the PC have a TCP server bound and listening on 192.168.43.194 on port 1998? Did you write the server code? If so, can you show it?

Comment: I have added the server code and the IP of the PC to my answer. Can you halp me figure out where is the bug?@Remy Lebeau

Comment: Your code does not match the error. The error message says the timeout occurred while connecting to port 9998, but the code is showing  port 1998 is being used on both sides. So where is 9998 coming from?

Comment: I used port 9998, then the problem occurs. So, I changed it to 1998, the same problem occurs again. Sorry for posting the code that does not match the logcat. I have editted my code. And it matched the logcat now. But I still do not know where the problem is. Thank you for helping me! @ Remy Lebeau